# Evaluating definite integral with u substituion

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

$$\int_1^2  \frac{dx}{3-5x^2}$$

Step 1: let u = 3-5x and -1/5 du = dx.

when x=2, u = -7 and when x=1, u = -2.

So now the integral becomes,

$$ -{1}/{5} \int_{-2}^{-7}  \frac{1}{u^2} du$$

and the integral of,

$$ \int\frac{1}{u^2} = -\frac{1}{u}$$

So,

$$-\frac{1}{5} *-\frac{1}{u} = (\frac{1}{5}) * \frac{1}{u}   $$

then plugging in the upper and lower limits for u,

$$\frac{1}{5} * (\frac{7}{14} - \frac{2}{14}) = \frac{1}{14} $$

I followed the solution from my textbook and understand what they did, however, the main problem I have is when they rewrote the integral in terms of u as,

$$ -{1}/{5} \int_{-2}^{-7}  \frac{1}{u^2} du$$

Specifically, the $$ \frac{1}{u^2} $$

is what bothers me most because

$$ u^2 = (3-5x)^2...$$
 NOT 
$$3-5x^2 $$

So can someone please explain to me why the textbook rewrote the integral as $$1/u^2$$??

Comment: Typo. It happens.

Comment: @AndrewChin. It is not a typo.. by making it 1 over u squared, it completely changes the equation..

Comment: if we square a function, it is the dependent variable that gets translated, not the independent x variable

Comment: The original function was probably meant to use $(3-5x) ^2$.

Comment: that makes sense